# How to get last executed function name using Javascript

Tags: javascript

**I am trying to get the name of the last executed function using JavaScript and this following code is working for me but need to find any other method is available? please help me:**

```
var fname;
function fn()
{
        fname="fn()";
} 

function fn1()
{
       fname="fn1()";
}

function fexecute()
{
       setTimeout(fname, 0);
}
```

I want to get finally executed function name and when i call fexecute() function at that time call last executed function.

Comment: What you want with the last executed function? Parallel callback?

Comment: I don't condone it, but you could change it to `setTimeout(fname+'()',0);` Make sure you read about the problems with using eval before you use it!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute a function name that you have in a string, you will have to do some besides just pass the string to `setTimeout()`. The best option would be to save a reference to the function directly rather than a string name.

```
var lastFunc;
function fn()
{
        lastFunc=fn;
} 

function fn1()
{
       lastFunc=fn1;
}

function fexecute()
{
       // execute previous function after a short timer
       setTimeout(lastFunc, 0);
}
```

If you don't need the `setTimeout()`, then you can execute the last function like this:

```
function fexecute()
{
       // execute previous function
       lastFunc();
}
```

Comment: i am already use this type but i want any other type methods.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `arguments.callee.name`

```
var fname;

function anyFunction () {
    fname = arguments.callee.name;
}

function anyOtherFunction () {
    fname = arguments.callee.name;
}
```

Call the functions normally like `anyFunction();` and `anyOtherFunction();`

Comment: arguments is not defined

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Hmm works for me in firefox as well.. did you try that jsfiddle?